# Renaming DbContext class loses association with existing migrations/modelsnapshot

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have been developing an Application using Ef-Core for a while, which means i have multiple existing migrations (including the ModelSnapshot). Now i have decided to start using SqlLite for local development (while the hosted version still uses SqlServer). To reflect this in the code i created two more Context classes

```
SqlServerContext : AppContext {}

SqlLiteContext : AppContext {}
```

where AppContext contains all the Db-Sets while the derivated classes set up the different connections and some additional configurations (like a data-seed for local development). These get added via Dependency Injection in the startup, depending on the environment.

When i create a new Migration using

```
dotnet-ef migrations add TestMigration --context SqlServerContext
```

it creates a new ModelSnapshot (SqlServerContextModelSnapshot.cs) instead of continuing to use the existing one (AppContextModelSnapshot.cs). I have to specify the Context since migrations are dependent on the Databaseprovider being used.

**Is there any way to tell my new Context to keep using the existing ModelSnapshot as a basis? Or am i using the context wrong and is there a better way to have environment specific databases and configurations?**

*Since the AppContext is already referenced everywhere in the project from the previous development, i would prefer not to simply rename the SqlServerContext to AppContext and the AppContext to something else (like BaseContext)*

Comment: What's the problem with SqlServerContextModelSnapshot.cs file and `SqlServerContextModelSnapshot` class names? They shouldn't be used by (thus affecting) other code, and the file/class is automatically regenerated on each add/remove migration command.

Comment: Just go through existing migrations and snapshot `.designer.cs` files and replace `[DbContext(typeof(AppContext))]` with `[DbContext(typeof(SqlServerContext))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ivan Stoev was right with his comment!

Just rename the `AppContextModelSnapshot.cs` to `SqlServerContextModelSnapshot.cs` and replace every appearence of `[DbContext(typeof(AppContext))]` with `[DbContext(typeof(SqlServerContext))]` inside the Snapshot and all the migrations.

Thanks!